# SimpleCv findkeypointmatch

Tags: opencv, simplecv

Could someone shed some light on why the following, in simplecv, does not work?

https://gist.github.com/2220293

Apparently, the image.findKeypointMatch attribute does not exist? It is indeed not the simplecv documentation.. How could I accomplish the something without this?

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Can you clarify the question? You're trying to run that script and get some errors?

Comment: Correct, it appears that "findKeypointMatch" is not an attribute of image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the one to write the above code.

The keypointmatch function is included in the latest github repository of simple. Install it from there. You also would be needing OpenCV 2.3 to run this.

Note: It is just an example for SimpleCV. This is in no way perfect, that is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the latest version of SimpleCV? If not I suggest you get the latest version from the repository. This library is very young, and after a quick look at the code I saw many bugs. So it's not a bad idea to go with the latest version hoping the number of bugs is reduced.

In 
    SimpleCV/ImageClass.py
you will find the findKeypointMatch() method. One thing you can do is to investigate why you cant call this function. If you copy here the error message you get and exactly the code you're trying to run then probably someone here can help you.

The other way is to go through the code as you wanted and see what it does and you copy the code in your script. I wouldn't recommend this.

Please let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

To verify you can always run:

```
import SimpleCV
print SimpleCV.__version__
```

Keypoint detection was added after 1.2.